# How to Tell if Dropbox API 503's are per-user or per-app

Tags: dropbox-api

I recently had a user who hit the Dropbox API at a very high rate and caused a large number of 503 responses.  According to the [Dropbox API documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api) a 503 is caused when 'Your app is making too many requests and is being rate limited. 503s can trigger on a per-app or per-user basis.'

The JSON body of the 503 response was as follows:

```
{"error": "Service Unavailable"}
```

This doesn't give me much information about on what basis I'm being throttled; per-app or per-user.  This could be very important as it will affect whether I attempt to back-off and throttle all of my applications requests to Dropbox, or only those for a specific user.

Is there any way to detect which basis such responses are occurring on?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I would love some more info about this as well. I contacted dropbox, but have not heard back from them. I am seeing it with some users of our app, but not for others, which makes me believe it is a per user restriction.

Comment: I am getting the same warning/error when I try to upload around 200 images to dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox will help you work around or increase your rate limits [if you ask](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact). I think the were purposefully ambiguous about what the rate limits means. Rate limits exist for a reason and I don't think Dropbox, or anyone, wants to give away the secret to circumventing them.

From the core docs as of July 8th, 2014

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

You'll receive a 503 if you're still using OAuth 1.0a as your authentication. You'll receive a 429 if you're using OAuth 2.0. But yea, they are unclear if it is per-app or per-user.

From [best practices](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/bestpractices) page they mention that you should [contact the developer team](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact) if you need to work around these limits.